# Google Cloud Translation Api - widget for commercial use

Tags: widget, google-translate, google-translation-api

The free "Google Translate Widget" is only available for non-commercial use. Is there an easy to use option for commercial use combined with the Google Cloud Translation Api?

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no option to use `Google Translate Widget` for commercial use or combined with `Google Cloud Translation API`. The [Google Translate Widget](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/05/google-translates-website-translator) will be restricted to government, non-profit, and/or non-commercial websites (for example, academic institutions) that focus on COVID-19 response. For all other websites, we recommend you to use only [Google Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate). It is a service that dynamically translates between languages with Google’s state-of-the-art Machine Learning models. It is a highly scalable API that supports over one hundred languages, with built-in language detection. Refer to this [blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/four-best-practices-for-translating-your-website) to know some best practices for optimizing cost, increasing performance, and hardening the security posture while using the Translation API with your websites.